# How to get data from streamreader into a new class

Tags: c#, .net, file, streamreader

I need to read in data from a text file, through steamreader, then move that information into another class (I named it info), finally move that into a textbox. I am not sure that I am doing this right at all, am new to it.
The error I get is "work2.info does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments"
So here's the code I have to read data in

```
    private void openToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "text files (*.txt)|*txt";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                StreamReader data = new StreamReader(myStream);

               string newinfo = data.ReadLine();
              string oldinfo = data.ReadLine();
                info pepinfo = new info(newinfo, oldinfo);
               pepinfo.newinfo = textBox1.Text;
               pepinfo.oldinfo = textBox2.Text;
```

The class I want to put the data in is

```
public class info
{

    public string newinfo
    {

    }
    public string oldinfo
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no constructor that takes 2 arguments in the code that you provided.
Your class could look like this:

```
public class Info
{
    public string NewInfo { get; private set; }

    public string OldInfo { get; private set; }

    public Info(string newInfo, string oldInfo)
    {
        NewInfo = newInfo;
        OldInfo = oldInfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: From the sample, he actually wants to present different lines in different textboxes, not all content in a single component.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your class (info), don't have a constructor that receives oldinfo and newinfo and populate the right stuff. Two options to change:

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "text files (*.txt)|*txt";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                StreamReader data = new StreamReader(myStream);

               string newinfo = data.ReadLine();
              string oldinfo = data.ReadLine();
                info pepinfo = new info();
               pepinfo.newinfo = newinfo;
               pepinfo.oldinfo = oldinfo;
```

Optionally, you can change your info class to add a constructor that receive two arguments, like the answer from Alex.